# Generic URL to latest pre-release package on NuGet?

Tags: url, package, nuget

The latest **stable** version of a *NuGet* package PACKAGE is easily located via the generic URL

> https://www.nuget.org/packages/PACKAGE/

Is there a generic URL analogue to the latest **pre-release** version of the same NuGet package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `absoluteLatest` like `https://www.nuget.org/packages/PACKAGE/absoluteLatest` seems to work these days.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got a response to this question on the *NuGet Gallery* [issues section](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery/issues/2567#issuecomment-115563667) on Github. Thanks, Maarten Balliauw!

---

**Maarten's response:** (slightly modified to sync with the original question)

There is no such URL currently. You could use the API to query for the latest prerelease of a package though, for example:

https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?Id=%27PACKAGE%27&$filter=IsPrerelease&$orderby=Version%20desc&$top=1

From this response, you can get the package URL.